# Python: fill NaN with value based on condition on other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe (sample) as given below (8K rows and 1.6K sellers)

```py
# initialise data of sells.
data = {
    'name': ['Tom', 'Tom', 'Tom', 'Tom', 'Tom', 'jack', 'jack', 'jack', 'jack',
             'jack', 'Malik'],
    'week': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1],
    'sell': [20, 21, 19, 18, 23, 24, 36, 35, 46, 50, 44],
}
# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Print the output.
df

######

# initialise data of demand.
data1 = {'name': ['Tom', 'Tom', 'Tom', 'jack', 'jack', 'jack', 'jack', 'Malik'],
         'week': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1],
         'demand': [28, 16, 43, 30, 35, 35, 72, 60]
         }

# Create DataFrame
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)

# Print the output.
df1
######
df2 = pd.merge(df, df1, on=['name', 'week'], how='outer')
df2['demand-sell'] = df2['demand'] - df2['sell']

df2
```

`df2`:

```
     name  week  sell  demand  demand-sell
0     Tom     1    20    28.0          8.0
1     Tom     2    21    16.0         -5.0
2     Tom     3    19    43.0         24.0
3     Tom     4    18     NaN          NaN
4     Tom     5    23     NaN          NaN
5    jack     1    24    30.0          6.0
6    jack     2    36    35.0         -1.0
7    jack     3    35    35.0          0.0
8    jack     4    46    72.0         26.0
9    jack     5    50     NaN          NaN
10  Malik     1    44    60.0         16.0
```

Expected Output:

Output_function

[image: Output_function]

**For week = 4**

In which I would like to fill **NaN** values of demand for **week = 4** with sum of remaining demand **(demand - sell)** of week = 1,2,3 of same the  seller (name)

**Note:**

If week=4 demand is not NaN then add week=4 demand in (demand - sell) of week = 1,2,3

{**ex.** in case of name = jack }

---

**For week = 5**
In which I would like to fill **NaN** values of demand for week = 5 with sum of remaining demand (demand - sell) of week = 1,2,3,4 of same the seller (name)

**Note:**

If week=5 demand is not NaN then add week=5 demand in (demand - sell) of week = 1,2,3,4

---

Output_sample_for_sample_data

[image: Output_sample_for_sample_data]

Comment: You've tagged `r` and `python3.x`. Which language are you looking for a solution in?

Comment: Removed teh [r]tag. The data was in non-R code.

Comment: @HenryEcker Python would be better.

Comment: @surex your row 8 doesn't have a `nan` value so why are you imputing it?

Comment: For the sake of uniformity in the calculation of demand for week 4 and 5. we have less than 0.01% of the data which also have demand in week 4 and 5. 
anyway it won't affect NaN of week=5  [(p + q + r + 72.0) - 46.0  = (p+q+r+s)], we can skip these cases as of now just take demand of week=4,5 as NaN every where